# Telerik MVC - Treeview - child node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I am using the following script to make a treeview:

> <% Html.Telerik().TreeView()
>           .Name("TreeView")
>
> ```
>     .Items(treeview =>
>     {
>         treeview.Add()
>             .Text("PART 1 ")
>             .Expanded(false)
>             .Content(() =>
>             {%>
>          <ul>
>         <li>text</li>
>         <li>text</li>
>         <li>text</li>
>         <li>text</li>
>     </ul>
>     <%});
>
>     }).Render();
>     %>
> ```

Any idea how I can add a child node inside the ul section that can expand?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Telerik website:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().TreeView()
        .Name("TreeView")
        .Items(item =>
        {
            item.Add()
                .Text("Mail")
                .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mail.gif")
                .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Mail Icon" })
                .Items(subItem =>
                {
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Personal Folders")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailPersonalFolders.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Personal Folders Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Deleted Items")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailDeletedItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Deleted Items Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Inbox")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailInbox.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Inbox Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Mail")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailFolder.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "My Mail Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Sent Items")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailSent.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Sent Items Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Outbox")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailOutbox.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Outbox Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Search Folders")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailSearch.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Search Folders Icon" });
                });
            item.Add()
                .Text("Contacts")
                .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contacts.gif")
                .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contacts Icon" })
                .Items((subItem) =>
                {
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Contacts")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contactsItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contact Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Address Cards")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contactsItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contact Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Phone List")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contactsItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contact Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Shared Contacts")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contactsItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contact Icon" });
                });
            item.Add()
                .Text("Tasks")
                .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasks.gif")
                .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Tasks Icon" })
                .Items((subItem) =>
                {
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Tasks")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasksItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Task Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Shared Tasks")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasksItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Task Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Active Tasks")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasksItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Task Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Completed Tasks")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasksItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Task Icon" });
                });
            item.Add()
                .Text("Notes")
                .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/notes.gif")
                .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Notes Icon" })
                .Items((subItem) =>
                {
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Notes")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/notesItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Note Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Notes List")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/notesItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Note Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Shared Notes")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/notesItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Note Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("Archive")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/notesItems.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Note Icon" });
                });
            item.Add()
                .Text("Folders List")
                .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/foldersList.gif")
                .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Folders List Icon" })
                .Items((subItem) =>
                {
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Client.Net")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailFolder.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Folder List Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Profile")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailFolder.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Folder List Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Support Tickets")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailFolder.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Folder List Icon" });
                    subItem.Add()
                           .Text("My Licenses")
                           .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailFolder.gif")
                           .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Folder List Icon" });
                });
        })
%>
```